# Getting data from database by textchanged event

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, linq-to-sql, textchanged

I'm trying to get data from my SQL Server database by textbox textchanged event. I wrote code but when I try to run it, it works but not fast enough.

How can I speed it up?

```
    Araclar arac = (from a in data.Araclars where a.AracSahibiTC == txtTc.Text select a).Single();
    txtPlaka.Text = arac.AracPlaka;
    txtSase.Text = arac.AracSaseNo;
    txtKm.Text = arac.AracKm;
    txtMarka.Text = arac.AracMarka;
    txtModel.Text = arac.AracModel;
```

Comment: How much fast you need? cause you may need to change your data framework, cause linq to sql is a bit slow by its own.

Comment: Data can come slowly it's not important. But I need to fix lagging while typing on textbox. Should I use bacgroundworker etc.?

Comment: It really depends on how many `Araclars` do you have. (whatever that is). Also, is it a web application? A Windows forms application? You could have that data cached if your database is not fast enough. It may also help to have the `AracSahibiTC` column indexed.